# Cannot use bash tab complete in tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

I just install tmux on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it throws me this error when I try to use tab completion for simple commands like 'cd' or 'mv' in the /etc/bash_completion file.

```
command substitution: line 74: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

However, I can use tab completion in my normal terminal or in byobu. Has anyone else encountered this issue or knows how to fix it? I do have the bash completion file included in my .bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar question, until I found [tmux and bash tab completion](https://web.archive.org/web/20140109014333/http://blog.e-thang.net/2012/08/14/tmux-and-bash-tab-completion/). Pretty good, colorful, explanation.

Reference:

- `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux`
- `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable`

Comment: Link says `This Account Has Been Suspended`. Ouch.

Comment: [recovered from cachd web page] Somewhere along the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, tmux, bash development chain someone decided to add this little gem of a key binding:

`bind-key -n     Tab clear-history`

They mapped that to clear the history, shutting down whatever else it may have done.  This one is SO ODD, that I can only imagine there was some really good and crazy reason for it.  
To overcome this “feature” add the following to your `.tmux.conf`.

`unbind -n Tab`

Comment: Booo, thanks for the assist, @AlessandroCuttin

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin that helped for me! Thank you!